Collision of two balls are getting stuck sometimes instead of bouncing off each other in html5 canvas
Balls do bounce, but sometimes they get stuck to each other.
Do tell if you need the rest of the code to solve this query.
This function is used to measure the distance between two balls.
    const measureDistance = (x1, y1, x2, y2) => {
        let result
        result = Math.pow(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2), 0.5)
        return result
    }

    function rotate(velocity, angle) {
        const rotatedVelocities = {
            x: velocity.dx * Math.cos(angle) - velocity.dy * Math.sin(angle),
            y: velocity.dx * Math.sin(angle) + velocity.dy * Math.cos(angle)
        };

        return rotatedVelocities;
    }
    const manageCollition = (tempArr, i, j) => {
        const angle = Math.tan(tempArr[j].dy - tempArr[i].dy / tempArr[j].dx - tempArr[i].dx)
        console.log(tempArr[j].dy - tempArr[i].dy / tempArr[j].dx - tempArr[i].dx)
        const u1 = rotate(tempArr[i], angle)
        const u2 = rotate(tempArr[j], angle)
        return { u1, u2 }

    }
    const checkCollisions = (ball, tempArr, i) => {
        let returnArr = tempArr;
        for (let j = 0; j < tempArr.length; j++) {
            if (j === i) continue
            const distance = measureDistance(ball.x, ball.y, tempArr[j].x, tempArr[j].y) - 2 * radius
            if (distance <= 0) {
                    const { u1, u2 } = manageCollition(tempArr, i, j)
                    returnArr = tempArr.map((element, index) => {
                        let newBall = element
                        if (index === i) {
                            newBall.dx = u1.x
                            newBall.dy = u1.y
                        }
                        if (index === j) {
                            newBall.dx = u2.x
                            newBall.dy = u2.y
                        }
                        return newBall
                    })
                }

            }
        return returnArr
    }

I think I made a mistake in physics or math somewhere.

Yes, is a common problem. You must check the collision before moving the balls. This is something you can do: calculate a future position for "ball" and tempArr (both). This future position is not what you see in the screen, is the position that will be used in the next iteration. Check the collision against it and they will bounce almost perfectly. May occur some edge cases with lots of objects, also if speed is too big, the collision may appear weird, but this method will solve most situations.

Thanks for the answer. I already tried that; it does not help

const checkCollisions = (tempArr, i) => {
    let returnArr = tempArr;
    for (let j = 0; j < tempArr.length; j++) {
        if (j === i) continue
        const distance = measureDistance(tempArr[i].x, tempArr[i].y, tempArr[j].x, tempArr[j].y) - 2 * radius
        const xVelocityDiff = tempArr[i].dx - tempArr[j].dx
        const yVelocityDiff = tempArr[i].dy - tempArr[j].dy
        const xDistance = tempArr[j].x - tempArr[i].x
        const yDistance = tempArr[j].y - tempArr[i].y
        if (distance <= 0) {
            if (xVelocityDiff * xDistance + yVelocityDiff * yDistance >= 0) {
                const { u1, u2 } = manageCollition(tempArr, i, j)
                returnArr = tempArr.map((element, index) => {
                    let newBall = element
                    if (index === i) {
                        newBall.dx = u1.x
                        newBall.dy = u1.y
                    }
                    if (index === j) {
                        newBall.dx = u2.x
                        newBall.dy = u2.y
                    }
                    return newBall
                })
            }

        }
    }
    return returnArr
}

Try this code for checkCollisions funtion.

Thank you for your solution. Could you explain what that if statement does?
